# Does it make sense to define a structure that is an inner product space and a K-algebra? And would this be useful in any way?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, bilinear-form

I've recently encountered K-algebras which I understand are different from inner product spaces in that one is equipped with a billinear *product* and the other with a bilinear *form*.

Is it possible and/or useful to define a space that has both of these operations? If so, what are some examples?

Comment: An an algebra the product is defined so that it is also a bilinear form. So you already have both. What are you looking for, exactly?  Clifford algebras have multiple products and forms on them, if that's what you want to dabble in.

Comment: @rschwieb I think the definition of "bilinear form on $A$" here is a map $A \otimes_K A \to K$. On the other hand, the multiplication of $A$ is a map $A \otimes_K A \to A$.

OP, it's important to note that an inner product is much more than just a bilinear form. For example, they can only be defined over ordered fields (or maybe in slightly more generality), because of the requirement of positive-definiteness. Also, the product on a $K$-algebra is (often) required to be unital and associative, beyond just bilinear.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yeah, that's probably right (about the intended definition.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to define both structures on some ring. A well-known example of such an object are the $\newcommand{\b}{\mathbb} \b{R}$-algebra of complex numbers with the conventional multiplication
\begin{align}
\b{C} \times \b{C} &\to \b{C} \\
(z, w) &\mapsto zw
\end{align}

and the inner product

\begin{align}
\b{C} \times \b{C} &\to \b{R} \\
(z, w) &\mapsto \operatorname{Re}(\bar{z} w)
\end{align}
Using polarization, the inner product is equivalent to the norm $|\cdot|: \b{C} \to \b{R}$. 
All these structures have been known to be useful.

However it should  be noted that, as is usual when defining multiple different structures on an object, these structures on $\b{C}$ are so useful, because they are **compatible**. In this particular case compatibility takes the form of the multiplication rule for absolute values $|z w| = |z| |w|$.

**Other examples I can think of:**

- Quaternions also are an $\b{R}$-algebra with an $\b{R}$-inner product satisfying the same compatibility as the complex numbers
- real or complex quadratic matrices matrices form a (noncommutative!) $\b{R}$-algebra with inner product $\left< A, B \right> = \operatorname{Re}(\operatorname{tr}(A^* B))$. The corresponding norm here is the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) $\|\cdot\|_F$. The compatibility here is weaker than in the above cases since the Frobenius norm is only *sub*multiplicative:
  $$
  \|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F \|B\|_F
  $$

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer, very interesting:)